# Bootstrap3 navbar doesn't close

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where the Bootstrap 3 navbar when it is converted into a dropdown menu on small devices (see code below). The issue is that once a menu link has been selected, the navbar dropdown doesn't close.

Any pointers where to start looking greatly appreciated.

```
<nav id="y-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="y-logo" src="images/template-logo.png" alt="logo"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a class="y-nav-link" data-partial="home.html" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="y-nav-about" class="y-nav-link" data-partial="about.html" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="y-nav-link" data-partial="contact-us.html" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="y-nav-link" data-partial="map.html" href="#">Directions</a></li>
                <!-- Page Layouts -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Layouts <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a class="y-nav-link" data-partial="feature-boxes.html" href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i> Feature Boxes</a></li>
                        <li><a class="y-nav-link" data-partial="four-blocks.html" href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i> Four Blocks</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Indeed, Bootstrap v3's navbar does not automatically collapse itself in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in a script to let the menu close after click:

```
    $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

See it working here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6vWL/89/)

[Reference here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12852)